# Mocking two functions in a method of another class

Tags: python, mocking, python-unittest

I've read multiple posts but I just not getting it and I've used the same methodology elsewhere and it worked but that was a method in another class, not a function.

plugins/iaw_api/helpers.py:

```
import requests
import json


def https_post_json(request_url, headers, data, timeout=20):
    response = requests.post(request_url, json=data, headers=headers, timeout=timeout)
    return json.loads(response.content)
```

plugins/iaw_api/iaw_api_runners.py:

```
from plugins.iaw_api.helpers import https_post_json


class IawApiRunner(object):

    def __init__(self, runner_class_in):

        self._runner_data_class = runner_class_in
        self.result = None

    def run_job(self):

        if type(self._runner_data_class) == SomeRunner:
            self._this_runner()

    def _this_runner(self):

        _task_id = https_post_json(<request-content>)
        print _task_id
```

tests/iaw_api/tests.py:

```
from plugins.iaw_api.helpers import https_post_json
from plugins.iaw_api.iaw_api_runners import IawApiRunner


class TestApiRunners(unittest.TestCase):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        super(TestApiRunners, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.test_runner = IawApiRunner(SomeRunner)

        def test_single_run_no_error(self):
            with mock.patch('plugins.iaw_api.helpers.https_post_json') as MockPost:
                MockPost.return_value = {'status_id': '59f0681cf9c32000132c7e89'}
                self.test_runner.run_job()
```

This is simplified and I've yet to add the assertions. The issue is when I run the test the actual http_post goes off to the API instead of the response being the mock return value.

Answer (score 0):

You have to patch the name used in the code you are *testing*; in this case, it is `https_post_json` (imported directly into the module namespace). Your patch would be correct if `iaw_api_runners.py` just used `import plugins` and `_this_runner` ran `_task_id = plugins.iaw_api.helpers.https_post_json(...)`.